# Running Python Selenium program outside of my PC

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Is there a way to run Selenium program outside of my PC? I'm happy with my code since its working as intended but running it over and over is annoying since its slowing my PC while opening and reloading browser. So my question is:
What should I use to run my script on something like host, Virtual Machines or something.
I'm pretty new to Selenium and Python so I dont know how to do it and i cant find enything useful on the internet that would help me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69050415/automated-browser-app-works-for-a-few-seconds-then-i-need-to-restart-pc, are you talking about this script ?

Comment: For example yes. But I will need that in future too since I have few more ideas that I would love to make. But running them while i work(motion design) would slow my PC.

Comment: Why not `Virtual Machines` ?

Comment: Thats the first thing i thought about. But before I test it I wanted to know is there something in "Selenium world" that is made especially for tasks like that. As I said im new to selenium so I'm discovering this freshly.

Comment: There is a headless mode, in which browser window will not open, and still script will get executed

Comment: But will headless mode collect data from browser extension? On my site I have one that is loading after like 2seconds after site is loaded showing text and everything else.

Comment: Headless is a same replica of real browser, but it is fast and unstable so try to put sleep for 5 seconds before the action that you've mentioned and you should be good to go.